Why is eth0.accept_ra sysctl value always overwritten even after specifying in sysctl.conf?
Ubuntu 22.04
I'm trying to configure an IPv6 network and want to accept autocofinguration via Router Advertisement messages. So I added the following lines
/etc/sysctl.conf:
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.all.accept_source_route = 1

net.ipv6.conf.eth0.forwarding = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra = 2
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_redirects = 1
net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_source_route = 1

The problem is after cable plug in/plug out or reboot the configuration is not even applied. If running sysctl -p the net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra is automatically overwritten by something to net.ipv6.conf.eth0.accept_ra=0 as well as other values.
It looks like a magic, I specified the hardcoded configuration which does not have any effect and sysctl -p got overwritten immediately after cable replug. Why that might happen?

One possible cause listed in man sysctl...
Verify that you do not have a "higher priority" file of the ones listed below, which may be nullifying your settings.
SYSTEM FILE PRECEDENCE
       When using the --system option, sysctl will read files from directories in the following list in given order from top to bottom. Once a file  of  a  given  filename  is
       loaded, any file of the same name in subsequent directories is ignored.

       /etc/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /run/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/local/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /usr/lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /lib/sysctl.d/*.conf
       /etc/sysctl.conf


$ sysctl --version
sysctl from procps-ng 4.0.4
$ . /etc/os-release ; echo $PRETTY_NAME
Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS

